# shouldn't uncheck checkbox in certain conditions

Tags: html, angular, checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="rowData.forA">  // checkbox A
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="rowData.forB">  // checkbox B
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="rowData.forC">  // checkbox C
```

I have these checkbox. And a model:

```
class Book {
  name: string;
  forA: boolean;
  forB: boolean;
  forC: boolean;
}
```

forA forB forC mean the book should be used in condition A, condition B or condition C.

In some conditions, if checkbox A is checked, and it's used in a kind of condition A, you cannot uncheck it. how to do that?

Comment: Just add a `readonly` attribute onto whichever one you dont' want the user to uncheck. So firstly, check which `checkbox` is checked, if it is one that has conditions attached to it, go in via `JS` or `JQuery` or whatever and add the readonly attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could use the `[readonly]`attribute with a condition inside

for example if you want `forA` to be readonly if `forB` and `forC` are checked you could do.

```
<input [readonly]="rowData.forB && rowData.forC" [(ngModel)]="rowData.forA">
```

Now if you don't want `readonly`but as told in the comment a checkbox checking automatically with condition you need to do the following

```
<input [checked]="rowData.forB && rowData.forC" [(ngModel)]="rowData.forA">
```

Comment: But I don'y want it to be readonly. What I want is, if uncheck that field which has been used by others, the checkbox checked automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$event.preventDefault()` based on your conditions. This is a sample of not allowing checkbox to be checked if `rowData.forB` is `true`:

```
<input type="checkbox" 
       [(ngModel)]="rowData.forA" 
       (click)="rowData.forB ? $event.preventDefault() : ''">
```